# Track usage of views and set up logging

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I set up a database with some views. I want to log who accessed which view and when. The target-table looks like this:

```
[schema], [table], [user], [timestamp] 
dbo, access, someuser, 2021-04-13 12:07:47.250
```

So every time someone opens a view, there should be a new row added with said data. As there aren't that many views, a "quick and dirty" solution would be fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only allow access via stored procedures. Let the SP log the wanted information.

Comment: Can't do that due to company regulations unfortunately. Company only allows access through views.

Comment: Then you are going to have to use extended events as the most lightweight approach that I can think of.